# Parse C# string to datetime with CET

Tags: c#, .net

How do I parse the sting "03/14/2016 12:41 CET" to date time object?

```
 DateTime.TryParseExact(x, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm CET", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out Output);
```

Comment: How many answers after @GrantWinney comment.. :)

Comment: Yes, got it. Thanks!! @GrantWinney

Comment: Using `hh` without `tt` is probably wrong as well, since a 12 hour clock is ambiguous without AM/PM marker. You probably want `HH` instead.

Answer (score 2):

MM stands for month and mm stands for minutes. So you need to use this:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(x, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm CET", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out Output);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `MM` which is stand for month, the `mm` stand for minutes, So please use the same with this way

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(x, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm CET", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out Output);
```

Also find [Standard Date and Time Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)